# open SQLite db on PC with android app

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

**open SQLite database on Windows with android app**

I want to share my db for android app 
I use by web service  
But is it possible with IP or the other way?

Comment: first line:i have a sqlite db on pc

Comment: you want to use same DB for multiple applications ? you question is not clear

Comment: @Rahul Patil  i have some android app and i want shared one SQLite db on windows with these application

Answer (score 0):

You can do these steps:

1) Add SQLite Manager plugin to your Firfox browser.

2) Restart browser.

3) Go to tools and oopen SQLite manager.

4) In SQLite manager you can browse and open sqlite db file.

Comment: ricintech thanks ,but i want use sqlite in my android application

Comment: If you are aware with the SQLite file and you want to use it in your android app then you can paste your sqlite file in assets folder and then open that file in database code. It will be done.

Comment: but i have more than one android app and i want shared db with these application, thanks again